# Run jar file in docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created a Docker image with java, and am copying the jar file into the image. 
My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
MAINTAINER myNAME 
COPY testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN java -jar /home/testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.j
```

After executing following command :

```
docker build -t imageName.
```

In the console I see the output from the application and everything is fine.
But when I stop the image, I don`t know how to run the image again ?
When I execute the following command :

```
docker run -i -t imageName java -jar /home/testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The application runs again, but in my Dockerfile I have already written this command. How can I run the image without this command and have the application run automatically?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

There is a difference between images and containers.

- Images will be built ONCE
- You can start containers from Images

In your case:

Change your image:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
MAINTAINER myNAME 
COPY testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/testprj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Build your image:

```
docker build -t imageName .
```

Now invoke your program inside a container:

```
docker run --name myProgram imageName
```

Now restart your program by restarting the container:

```
docker restart myProgram
```

Your program changed? Rebuild the image!:

```
docker rmi imageName
docker build -t imageName .
```

Comment: but then each time if we change the version of pom, we have to change the Dockerfile too, it could be easily forgotten

Answer (score 12):

This may not be quite what you asked, but if you *just* need to run a JAR (rather than that being just one part of a larger custom container) I like this approach of mapping a volume/folder to the JAR and running it using a standard upstream image:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home/me/folderHoldingJar:/home:Z java:latest /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/java -jar /home/theJarFile.jar'
```

There is even [some additional args](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-can-i-use-podman-to-run-a-wayland-app/1672) you can add if the JAR needs to display a GUI.

Comment: What if I want the application.jar already running when I start the container? Is it possible to create an image which has my .jar started so I don't have to wait for it to start when I spin up a container? For example if I start my app like `java -jar app.jar` it takes 20 seconds until it is ready to be accessible over localhost:8080. When I start it from a container I would like it to be ready without waiting 20 seconds. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Wlad This never used to be possible with Java.  Only recently [CRaC](https://github.com/CRaC/docs) "Coordinated Restore at Checkpoint" has started to catch on.  If your app supports it, you could get the app running and then snapshot it.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer but I prefer sharing my running command.

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar", "jar-file-name.jar" ]
```